# How can other players view my individual Kills & Deaths?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Somebody pointed out my exact kills and deaths while playing on a casual server. How could they see this?

Was it a custom scoreboard that shows kills and deaths of all players, or how else would he know my stats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `tf_scoreboard_mouse_mode` you can interact with it and click on another users name to view their stats.

`tf_scoreboard_mouse_mode 1
tf_scoreboard_mouse_mode 2`

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scoreboard#Enable_mouse_input_on_the_scoreboard

This was from ~3 years ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/3ch15t/psa_the_scoreboard_has_a_new_mouse_mode/

Comment: I used the mouse mode, I didn't realise that I could click on other players and view their stats.